# Repeated point creation

Tags: c#

I am using MousePosition to try to determine which way the user moves his or her mouse after the MouseDown event is triggered. The problem is I am trying to make a starting variable using Point datatype and I only want this Point to be filled with data once but I have it in a MouseDown so I can use the mouse arguments e.X and e.Y to determine where the MouseDown event was called. Here is an example of what im thinking of

```
public void panel1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    Point start = new Point(e.X, e.Y);
}
public void panel1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if(MousePosition.X > start.X)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("you have moved right");
    }
}
```

so how would I only create that start variable once while still having it have access to the e mouse argument. and also how would I access the variable  between panel1_MouseDown and panel1_MouseMove? If you see a better alternative to doing this too that would be great! Thank you all for the help!

Comment: You can't have a local variable read by other function. What's the problem with having a class member (along with a boolean one which determines whether the mouse is down or not)?

Also, since `Point` is a value type (a `struct`), you can't have it "uninitialized" (i.e., its value can't be `null`)

Comment: Make `start` a private variable in your class, and lose the type declaration (`Point`) in the MouseDown method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have aversion to define new class members (for some reason), this is the least you could have:

```
Point? start = null;
public void panel1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    start = new Point(e.X, e.Y);
}
public void panel1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    start = null;
}
public void panel1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if(start.HasValue)
      if(MousePosition.X > start.Value.X)
        Console.WriteLine("you have moved right");
}
```

But for clarity (and functionality) I'd have an additional boolean variable:

```
bool mouseIsDown = false;
Point start;

public void panel1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    start = new Point(e.X, e.Y);
    mouseIsDown = true;
}
public void panel1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    mouseIsDown = false;
}
public void panel1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if(mouseIsDown)
      if(MousePosition.X > start.X)
        Console.WriteLine("you have moved right");
}
```

Comment: I didnt think of that I see now thank you so much :)

Answer (score 2):

declare your start point as private class variable

```
Private Point start;

public void panel1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    this.start = new Point(e.X, e.Y);
}
public void panel1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
        if(MousePosition.X > this.start.X)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("you have moved right");
        }
}
```

Comment: that what I was trying to write from him, just add in panel1_mousedown, if(start == default(Point)) , or the user will initiate the start each time he press the mouse down

Comment: `Point` is a `struct`, and can't be null

Comment: you can use default(Point) instead or make it nullable => Point? then you can assign null to it

Comment: @HadiHassan `default(Point)` would more likely be a `Point(0,0)`, which is a perfectly valid value and by no means would necessarily mean "uninitialized"